# How to change color of link and effect on hover using CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replicate the "AC Wall Plug Adapter Recall Program" text header on this [apple clone website](https://altcademy.github.io/apple_clone/), its the blue text located right above the footer. I have succeeded in centering the text, but I need some help in making the text link blue and when I hover my mouse over the text, it should become underlined. I know it must be the CSS `:hover` selector, but I don't know how to place it within my CSS. Also, I am a amateur at coding, so I would really appreciate it if you could explain my mistakes instead of just giving me the answer, thank you.

```css
.ac-pro {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

a.ac-pro {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h2 class="ac-pro"><a href="#">AC Wall Plug Adapter Recall Program ></a></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are trying to change the colour of the link when it's hovered over.

The CSS you are currently using isn't quite right.  There is no `a.ac-pro` because the class `ac-pro` is set on the `h2`.

Once way to resolve this is to fix the CSS so that it applies to the `a` underneath `h2.ac-pro`:

```
h2.ac-pro > a {
```

Then simply add a new CSS style for the hover:

```
h2.ac-pro > a:hover {
```

The snippet shows this in action:

```css
.ac-pro {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

h2.ac-pro > a {
  color: blue;
}

h2.ac-pro > a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h2 class="ac-pro"><a href="#">AC Wall Plug Adapter Recall Program ></a></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .ac-pro {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

  .ac-pro a {
  color: blue;
text-decoration : none;

}
.ac-pro a:hover {
  color: red;

}
```

> you were not targetting the class properly
> try this it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you are not applying class and tags properly. please try this.
this will help you in making text-line blue and when you hover it it will become underline.

**code:**

```
<div class="container">
<h2 class="ac-pro"><a href="#">AC Wall Plug Adapter Recall Program ></a></h2>
</div>

.ac-pro {
text-align: center;
color: blue;
}

.ac-pro > a{
text-decoration: none;
}

.ac-pro > a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 }
```